# Can I check a checkbox outside of an HTML input tag?

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I am writing a php site that has a form with a series of check boxes.  I will be loading an array from a file that I would like to go through and check some of the boxes by default when the form is loaded.

Here is an example:

```
<form action="mypage.php">
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="option1" />
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="option2" />
    <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="option3" />
</form>

<?php
    $array = array("option1", "option3");
    //  for loop to check boxes 1 and 3.
?>
```

Is this possible?  What would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fill your array before the HTML part. And then:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="option1" <?php if (in_array("option1", $array)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
    $array = array("option1", "option3");
    //  for loop to check boxes 1 and 3.
?>

<form action="mypage.php">
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="option1" <?php if(in_array("option1",$array)){?> checked="checked"<?php}?> />
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="option2" <?php if(in_array("option2",$array)){?> checked="checked"<?php}?> />
    <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="option3" <?php if(in_array("option3",$array)){?> checked="checked"<?php}?> />
</form>
```

Comment: Please note that you have to put the array (php code) above the html code